# How to retrieve the 'last sync' time for an account?

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter

Is it possible to retrieve the time an account was last synchronized, like the system Settings->Accounts&Sync app does? I'm using Android 2.2.

Looking at the 2.2 source for `AccountSyncSettings.java`, I see the status is retrieved using:

```
SyncStatusInfo status = ContentResolver.getSyncStatus(account, authority);
```

but SyncStatusInfo and getSyncStatus don't seem to be part of the public API (marked with @hide). Is there some other way to get at this info?

Answer (score 3):

You can use reflection to achieve this purpose.Here is my code to implement this

```
private long getLasySyncTime() {
    long result = 0;
    try {
        Method getSyncStatus = ContentResolver.class.getMethod(
                "getSyncStatus", Account.class, String.class);
        if (mAccount != null && mSyncAdapter != null) {
            Object status = getSyncStatus.invoke(null, mAccount,
                    mSyncAdapter.authority);
            Class<?> statusClass = Class
                    .forName("android.content.SyncStatusInfo");
            boolean isStatusObject = statusClass.isInstance(status);
            if (isStatusObject) {
                Field successTime = statusClass.getField("lastSuccessTime");
                result = successTime.getLong(status);
                TLog.d(WeixinSetting.class, "get last sync time %d", result);
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        TLog.d(WeixinSetting.class, e.getMessage() + e.getCause().getMessage());

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Settings app uses `ContentResolver.getSyncStatus(account, authority)`. However, this is not part of the public API. You can use it, but it could break with any future release.